# Getting "cannot find symbol" error while using static methods

Tags: java, static-methods

I have really simple code, I have deleted odd code.

So this my class, one of his method is static and I would like to use it later in `Main class`:

```
public  class  TradeInformationReader {

 private static String tradeType = "FX_SPOT";
 public static double tradePrice = -1;
 private double price;

 public  static int setTradeInformation(String path_to_file) {
 return 1;
  }
 }
```

And here how I trying to call this last method:

```
public class Main {

public static int main(String[] args) {

    String path_to_file = "D:\\1.txt";
    if (0 > TradeInformationReader.setTradeInformation(path_to_file)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
 }
}
```

I read many posts with a similar issue, but couldn't find a solution. Everything looks fine to me. IDE doesn't show any mistakes and I'm trying just to call static method `setTradeInformation`, why it does not recognize it (cannot find symbol method `setTradeInformation`)? Any ideas? I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the symbol which is not recognized ?

Comment: why setTradeInformation returns 1 all the time?

Comment: @Kick Buttowski I think is just an example... He knows that it will never enter the second IF condition if the implementation was really that.

Comment: Is `TradeInformationReader` an inner class ? (not defined in its own file)

Comment: @NicolasAlbert I call static method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your main is not a valid main, so I guess your IDE cannot find a launching class. This should be

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: @Dice That`s really strange, now it works, why using void is so important?

Comment: @Rocketq that's how you define the "entry point" of your mini app.

Comment: That's how Alboz said ! Note that in C and C++, `main` returns an int.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to put TradeInformationReader  class in a seperate file called : TradeInformationReader.java

as follows : `

```
public  class  TradeInformationReader {

 private static String tradeType = "FX_SPOT";
 public static double tradePrice = -1;
 private double price;

 public  static int setTradeInformation(String path_to_file) {

    //integer to identify whether the file is found or not 1 if found and 0 if not
    int isFileFound = 1;

    // the code required to get the file and modify the state of the of isFileFound variable

    return isFileFound;
  }
 }
```

`

then  the main class should  have void return type and should be in a file that has the same name as the Main Class as follows:

```
 public class firstApp {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

String path_to_file = "D:\\1.txt";
if (0 > TradeInformationReader.setTradeInformation(path_to_file)) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

}
}
`